# Django – remove the trailing slash from 'sitemap.xml/'

Tags: django, xml-sitemap, django-sitemaps

I am using Django's sitemap framework and have a sitemap index. My urls file looks like this:

```
urls = [
    path('', include('movies.urls')),
    path('', include('accounts.urls')),
    ...
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(*urls, prefix_default_language=True,)

sitemaps = {
    'main': MainSitemap,
    'movies': MoviesSitemap,
}

urlpatterns.extend([
    path('sitemap.xml', views.index, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
    path('sitemap-<section>.xml', views.sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps},
     name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
])
```

This is implemented in accordance with the recommendations in the [documentation of Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/sitemaps/).

The problem is that I always get 404 when trying to access my sitemap index: *example.com/sitemap.xml*. This occurs because a redirect occurs automatically to the non-existent *example.com/sitemap.xml/* URL with a trailing slash.

How can I avoid a slash being appended to the .xml sitemap file? I have tried using re_path but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent Django from automatically appending slash to urls by putting this line in your settings file:

```py
APPEND_SLASH = False
```

But I think a better way would be to use

```py
path('sitemap.xml/', views.index, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
```

in `urlpatterns`. I'm not sure if the second solution works, but it should.

---

**Update:**

As can be seen in the other answer you can use `re_path` with optional trailing slash:

```py
from django.urls import re_path

re_path(r'sitemap.xml/?$', views.index, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
```

Comment: It works but it does not suit me. I need my sitemap URL to be without a trailing slash. The first solution is not suitable either because I need a trailing slash in all other URLs.

Comment: Ok. If you set `APPEND_SLASH` to `True`, and also append use the aforementioned line in you urlpatterns, Django will automatically redirect requests without trailing slash to the  path containing the trailing slash.
This way you receive your sitemap on both `/sitemap.xml` and `/sitemap.xml/`.

Comment: Not really. I will be redirected to /sitemap.xml/. Always. This does not suit me because the content-type of the page becomes 'text/xml' instead of 'application/xml,' which, I believe, is causing troubles with Google indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re_path` instead of `path` to use regular expression in your url pattern. Use `?` sign in your url like this:

```py
from django.urls import re_path
re_path(r'sitemap.xml/?$', views.appmain, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
```

Comment: This automatically redirects me to the sitemap URL with a trailing slash, which is why I started this question. This does not suit me because the content-type of the page becomes 'text/xml' instead of 'application/xml,' which, I believe, is causing troubles with Google indexing.

Comment: @Edmond I confirm this works. Redirection won't happen in this case. If you're still redirected, that's because you browser cached the redirect response. Try the URL in an incognito tab.

Comment: Now the worst thing. Everything worked with my code from the very beginning, no need to use anything more than in Django documentation. The problem was in my browser's cache... Thanks.